# Is there any standard API in Linux to extract language("en") from locale("en_US.UTF-8")?

Tags: c++, linux, locale, setlocale

I want to extract abbreviated language name from the given locale.
For Example: en_US.UTF-8 should return "en" not "English".
Is there any standard API instead of parsing the locale name manually?